# Rigorous formula for adjusted close price

Tags: equities, dividends, adjustments

I'm a mathematician who is new to the stock market, and I'm hoping to shine a rigorous light on a simple example of adjusting close prices for, say, dividends.

Let time $t$ represent today. Say that the price of a stock two days ago (at time $t-2$) was $p_{t-2}=4$. Then, yesterday, the price climbs to $p_{t-1}=6$, and the stock pays a dividend of $d=1$. Today, let the stock price by $p_t=4$. If I'm correct, today would be called the 'ex-dividend date'.

If I bought the stock two days ago and sold it today, I would think that the appropriate calculation for my return (assuming no dividend reinvestment) is $\frac{p_t + d}{p_{t-2}} = 1.25,$ or $25\%$.

However, in most of the explanations I see online, they do the following: adjust the prices on $t-1$ and before by multiplying these prices by the quantity $(1-\frac{d}{p_{t-1}})$. If I use this adjusted price at time $t-2$, I would get: $p'_{t-2} = p_{t-2}(1-\frac{d}{p_{t-1}}) \approx 3.33$. If I then use the formula $\frac{p_t}{p'_{t-2}}$ for my return, I get $1.2,$ or $20\%$.

I would think that my return is $25\%$, but this popular formula does not agree. I notice that in order to derive an adjusted price $p'_{t-2}$ which gives the true return today, this adjusted price would need to be a function of $p_t$, implying that these adjusted prices would need to continually be adjusted every day. Perhaps this is cumbersome or inconvenient, so people settle for the popular formula as an approximation (which only needs to be adjusted when another dividend is paid or a split is made), but I'm not sure. Maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong. Any ideas of why these two formulae aren't rectifying/any good references are very much appreciated. Thanks!

An edit, since I can't comment:

nbbo2 - Thanks for the link, that's helpful. I suppose this version of adjusted price, in which the adjustment factor is fixed (until next dividend) and doesn't depend on today's price, is just a convenient approximation.

AlRacoon- Here's the sample calculation that yahoo finance gives: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28256.html. This paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2956 also explains the common formula very nicely.

After thinking about this some more, I suppose there's an interpretation that justifies the formula in the links above: if you *knew* a \$0.1 dividend was coming next week, and you bought the stock for \$1 today, you could think of having bought the stock for \$0.9 today when you come back to adjust. Anyway, thanks for your help everyone. Was a good exercise to think about this.

Comment: I think there is another question on this site that discusses this. You are right that the method commonly used by Yahoo etc. to "adjust" prices for dividends is only an approximation and does not give  a correct Total Return in general.

Comment: This is one post that addressed the question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42445/total-returns-from-adjusted-close-prices There may be others as well.

Comment: Could you provide the source for your price adjustment?