Total Return vs Adjusted Price Return
I have a question regarding the difference between the total return index and adjusted price for the index.
Based on what I know...

Total return index assumes dividend reinvestment.
Adjusted price 'adjust' for dividend. If there arises a certain amount of dividend, then as an investor actually gets both 'dividend return' + 'price return', so the adjusted price should reflect the return part from dividend, wiping out the impact of ex-dividend.

If so, I think that two concepts are basically same in a sense that it has a concept of 'dividend reinvestment'.
What's the difference behind those 2 concepts?

The investor earns the total return. The adjusted price return is an approximation of the TR but is not what the investor actually earns. The TR was developped in academia, the APR was invented or popularized by data companies like Yahoo Finance so their charts would not show a sudden drop when a stock pays a dividend. For serious work use the TR. (There is a post here that discusses this in more detail https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42445/total-returns-from-adjusted-close-prices/42472#42472 ).

Thanks a lot! Things have become much more clear but I still need more time to fully digest the contents from the link you attached :) Thank you

If there is a 1.00 USD dividend, the Adjusted Price technique adds 1.00 to the price, so it is an arithmetic (or additive) adjustment. It is good for drawing price charts and (maybe) for short term evaluation of performance. The TR is a percentage concept so it works differently (multiplication/division) and will give different result over long periods when there are multiple dividends occurring with reinvestment. It is the better method for long term inv performance eval.

Got it. so the adjusted price is just a technique to make chart in more successive way.

Many backtest curriculum floating on the internet recommends to use adjusted price, and it's quite surprising that those whole things trigger at least some level of distortion...
